# Rendering multiple input fields causing lag after 200 items

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, textfield, next.js

I have a project where i can have n-number of input field. After when i add 200 items, it starts lagging after that. Demo : https://testcreate.vivekneel.now.sh/create **(To test: Focus last input and try pressing enter button to create new input)**

Source Code. : https://github.com/VivekNeel/Create-Test

This is my main container :

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import CreateTerms from "./CreateTerms";
import { initTerms, contructTermObject } from "./utils";
import { Container } from "@material-ui/core/";

const CreateStudySetContainer = () => {
  const [terms, setTerms] = useState(initTerms);

  const [inputIdToFocus, setInputIdToFocus] = useState(null);

  const handleCreateTerm = () => {
    const newTerm = contructTermObject(terms.length + 1, 2);
    const newTerms = [...terms, newTerm];
    setInputIdToFocus(terms.length + 1);
    setTerms(newTerms);
  };
  console.log("....rendering");
  return (
    <Container maxWidth={"md"}>
      <CreateTerms
        terms={terms}
        inputIdToFocus={inputIdToFocus}
        createTerm={handleCreateTerm}
      />
      ;
    </Container>
  );
};

export default CreateStudySetContainer;
```

This the CreateTerms code :

```
import React from "react";
import CreateFacts from "./CreateFacts";

import { withStyles, Card } from "@material-ui/core/";
import ContentItemRow from "./ContentItemRow";
const styles = () => ({
  card: {
    marginBottom: 16,
  },
});
const CreateTerms = (props) => {
  const { terms, classes, createTerm, inputIdToFocus } = props;
  return (
    <div className={classes.container}>
      {terms.map(({ node: { term } }, index) => {
        return (
          <Card key={term.id} className={classes.card}>
            <p>{index}</p>
            <ContentItemRow
              autoFocus={term.id === inputIdToFocus}
              createTerm={createTerm}
              term={term}
            />
            ;
          </Card>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default withStyles(styles)(CreateTerms);
```

This is ContentItemRow :

```
import React from "react";
import CreateFacts from "./CreateFacts";

import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/";
import ContentEditor from "./ContentEditor";
const styles = {
  container: {
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "flex-start",
  },
  term: {
    marginRight: 16,
    flex: 1,
  },
  facts: {
    flex: 1,
  },
};

const ContentItemRow = (props) => {
  const { term, classes, createTerm, autoFocus } = props;
  return (
    <div className={classes.container}>
      <div className={classes.term}>
        <ContentEditor
          autoFocus={autoFocus}
          createTerm={createTerm}
          placeholder={"New term"}
        />
      </div>
      <div className={classes.facts}>
        {term.facts.map(({ fact }) => {
          return (
            <ContentEditor
              key={fact.id}
              createTerm={createTerm}
              placeholder={"New fact"}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default withStyles(styles)(ContentItemRow);
```

This is ContentEditor :

```
import React from "react";

import { TextField } from "@material-ui/core/";

const ContentEditor = (props) => {
  const { placeholder, createTerm, autoFocus } = props;

  const handleOnKeyDown = (event) => {
    const { keyCode } = event;
    if (keyCode === 13) {
      createTerm();
    }
  };
  return (
    <TextField
      onKeyDown={handleOnKeyDown}
      fullWidth
      autoFocus={autoFocus}
      placeholder={placeholder}
    />
  );
};

export default ContentEditor;
```

When debugging, I noticed that dom updates only the last div which gets added. I don't know where the lagging is coming from.

Comment: Does it lag significantly more with `200` items than it does with `199` items?

Comment: It's the same for 199th items as well!

Comment: In your case, "200 items" doesn't mean rendering about 200 components, not even close. According to your code, for each item, you render 1 "term" input and _i_ "fact" inputs, so if I'm not wrong, you're actually rendering at least 200 + 20100 = 20200 components (!!!). I guess that's quite a lot for React to handle (it takes a whooping ~500MB memory).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will work but you can try the following:

```
const ContentItemRow = React.memo(function ContentItemRow (props) => {
```

And to prevent re creating the create term handler:

```
const handleCreateTerm = useCallback(() => {
  setTerms((terms) => {
    const newTerm = contructTermObject(
      terms.length + 1,
      2
    );
    const newTerms = [...terms, newTerm];
    setInputIdToFocus(terms.length + 1);
    return newTerms;
  });
}, []);
```

Comment: It's not the every things is rendering in the dom. It's only the last div which is getting updated it dom. So react already skips the rendering. Am still wondering why this is still slow when it just the last div getting updated in dom.

Comment: I want to optimize without using React.memo since even memo will take time doing shallow checks for all the items!

Comment: `It's not the every things is rendering in the dom. ` I don't think so, did you try profiler in react dev tools? You are re creating a handler on every render and that would fail virtual dom compare and cause every item to re render.

Comment: I tried your solution, seems to be working. But since there is no deps for useCallback, am able to add just another one input not more than that.